# Does one "forebode something on/upon someone"?

Tags: prepositions

Can one use forebode + obj. + on/upon someone? For example, would a sentence like `His coming foreboded doom on/upon the village` be considered correct (in a sense that it predicted doom for the village) or would one rather use `for`?

Comment: Note that the past form of *forebode* is *forebode**d***.

Comment: The use of "forebode" already has an dramatic-archaic feel so while "on" would be grammatical you might as well go for the more dramatic "upon", e.g. "I shall wreak mine vengeance upon thee and thy kin unto the youngest generation!"  Might be a bit more dramatic than your example, though.  :)

Comment: @Andrew Oh well, I couldn't really think of a good example :)

Comment: @BenSteffan your example is fine, I just went full Old Testament on it.  Seriously though it's not really usual to use "forbode" in a sentence, unless you are intentionally talking like something out of the Lord of the Rings.

Comment: @Andrew It was about a school assignment (actually, interpreting a cariccature). The teacher thought my text was great, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Forebode* does not take a recipient, either as an indirect object or a prepositional oblique.

With *forebode doom upon X*, the preposition phrase is therefore not a complement to *forebode* but a modifier on *doom*: what is foreboded is that doom will fall upon X.

*Doom **for** X* to my ear works even better.